# Package manager errors on my ubuntu

Tags: apt

I have this issues with my ubuntu apt-get update 
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Ex18v2Ku

```
ubilli@ubilli-pc ~> sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ubilli:
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease  
.    
.
.
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en        
Fetched 459 kB in 25s (17.7 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn\'t be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D1106511179518B2
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Comment: @S.L.Barth please what do i  do...

Comment: @ubili Take a look at the answer in the linked post. If that doesn't help you, edit your question, and explain why the answer there didn't help. Good luck!

Comment: [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

**[UPDATE]**

Run:

```
gpg --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Then:

```
gpg --export 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 | apt-key add --
```

Comment: i did what you said and this is the output  http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=yA1hNg0a

Comment: Run:
gpg --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

Then:
gpg --export 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 | apt-key add -

Comment: ubilli@ubilli-pc /v/l/apt> sudo su
root@ubilli-pc:/var/lib/apt# gpg --export 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 | apt-key add --
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: this is the output..

Comment: please @Subv3rsion this is the output

Comment: Run: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32; gpg --export --armor 313D312748A22A95 | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Pp9Pzd7M   this is the output...

Comment: run sudo apt-get clean and then sudo apt-get update

Comment: wow it is no more showing the errors thanks guys  Subv3rsion and  S.L. Barth

Comment: You should close your question,

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a key and apt is unable to authenticate the repository. Run this command to fix it:

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32`